# misuse of aggregate: group_concat()

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem with sqlite3 in this string

```
select group_concat(persons.name, ', ') as Актеры 
from films_persons join persons on persons.id = films_persons.person_id 
where films_persons.film_id = 1 and role = Актеры
```

films_persons looks like this:

```
film_id | person_id |              role
   1    |     1     | "Actors" (or "Актеры" in my case)
```

persons:

```
id |    name   | birth_date
 1 |  Leonardo | 11.11.1974
```

I need to group all persons.name in 1 string, and this call must return "Leonardo".

Full name of error is "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate: group_concat()".

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is mysql3? What's the problem with your sql statement?

Comment: @Shadow, I write "mysql3" in linux command line to operate my data base. And the ERROR name is in the title. Full name of ERROR is "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate: group_concat()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql, you need to do:

```
group_concat(persons.name separator ', ')
```

instead of:

```
group_concat(persons.name, ', ')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=20172b9b99dfcf7dcdf7ccf00efd49f4

But it appears from your error that you are using sqlite, not mysql, in which case your syntax is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=691caef008dbade5c1dde83e4e495c7f

Comment: If i write it like this `group_concat(persons.name separator ', ')`, console says that there is an error near `separator`. I have added a comma before `separator`, but nothing has changed: `(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "', '": syntax error`

Comment: Oh, i've found mistake. I was using not full name for column. Your example showed me that. Thank you very much. Sorry for wasting your time.